# After posting JSON with jQuery, convert the string back into a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have some code that posts this JSON:

```js
post = {
    period: "1",
    data: {1: "Here"}
}
```

And it is posted with this code:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/',
    data: post,
    type: 'POST'
})
```

When I execute this code, my server receives this string: `"period=1&data%5B3%5D=Here"`

Is there a way to convert this string back into a JSON?

I have tried `JSON.parse()` but that obviously did not work.

Comment: what sort of server are you using? PHP, nodejs / express, etc.?

Comment: I am using a node.js

Comment: Did you try body parser middle ware in nodejs or express ?

Comment: Have you tried stringifying your object before sending it: `data: JSON.stringify(post)` (also adding: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`)? If you're using express you can use urlencoded() middleware to parse the url-encoded string to an object

Comment: Change it to `data: JSON.stringify(post)` and see if that makes a difference because I don't think jQuery automatically serialises data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was never JSON, you can send it as JSON by using JSON.stringify and then use JSON.parse to get it back as an object on the server.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/',
    data: JSON.stringify(post),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string with the [`URLSearchParams` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams), then use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert it to an object:

```js
const obj = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams("period=1&data%5B3%5D=Here"));
console.log(obj)
```